# Layer 3 firewall port forwarding

Tags: networking

I want to send the packets from one port(eg. Port.No.1) to two other ports(Port.No. 2 & 3) kind of port forwarding in layer 3 firewall. I just tried to use the port forwarding but it's not sending to both the ports and its sending to anyone which is having least priority setting.

Can anyone advise me

Comment: Can you specify what hardware you are using?

Comment: I am trying with Hirchman 6 port Firewall.

Comment: Can you add an exact model number. Hirchman website doesn't immediately show a "6 port Firewall"  Lots of switches but don't immediately see a firewall.  An exact model will be a great help

Comment: This is the exact model EAGLE30-04022O6TT999TKKV9HSE3FXX.X.